# How can I force a controller's TempData to be populated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller

## Background

I'm fixing an issue on an window in an MVC environment in which pushing a toggle button does not cause the data to update, making a refresh necessary instead.

## Files

### Foos\Index.cshtml

```
<environment>
    <script src="~/js/services/fooController.js"/>
</environment>
<div ng-controller="FooController" ng-init="loadFoos()" ng-cloak>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="foo in foos" ng-click="null">
        <div layout="row">
            <div>{{foo.name}}</div>
            <div>{{foo.flag}}</div>
            <div>
                <md-button ng-click="toggleFlag(foo)">
                    <md-icon>myIcon</md_icon>
                </md-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-list-item>
</div>
```

### fooController.js

```
app.controller('FooController', ['$scope', 'fooService', function($scope, fooService) {
    $scope.loadFoos = function() {
        fooService.Load().then(function (response) {
            $scope.foos = response.foos;
        });
    };

    $scope.toggleFlag = function(foo) {
        fooService.toggleFlag(foo).then(function () {
            $scope.loadFoos();
        });
    }
}]);
```

### fooService.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('MyModule').factory('fooService', ['$http', fooService]);

    function fooService($http) {
        return {
            loadFoos: loadFoos,
            toggleFlag: toggleFlag
        };

        function loadFoos() {
            return $http.get("/Foos/Foos").then(successCallBack);
        }

        function toggleFlag(foo) {
            return $http.post("/Foos/ToggleFlag", foo);
        }

        function successCallBack(response) {
            return response.data;
        }
    };
})();
```

### FooController.cs

Finally, this all comes back to a C# controller, which looks like this:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [Route("/Users/{userId}/Foos")]
    public IActionResult Index(int userId)
    {
        this.TempData["userId"] = userId;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Foos()
    {
        var userId = int.Parse(this.TempData["userId"].ToString());
        IEnumerable<Foo> foos = new Foo[0];
        //to keep this as small as possible for reproducing
        return this.Json(new { foos = foos });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/Foos/ToggleFlag")]
    public ActionResult ToggleFlag([FromBody] Foo foo)
    {
        //delegate updating to writer; omitted for reproducibility
        return this.Ok();
    }
}
```

## The Underlying Problem

When the window loads, `Index()` gets called and automagically fills `TempData` with the appropriate user ID from the URL. It can then call `Foos()` and return the appropriate list. However, when invoked through `$scope.toggleFlag`, it **doesn't** call `Index()`, making `Foos()` throw an exception when it tries to access the nonexistent `TempData["userId"]`.

## The Question

How can I get `TempData` to be filled whenever `Foos()` gets called, or increase the lifespan of the controller?

Comment: `TempData` is designed for one time use. use a `Session` variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

A session variable should work.

TempData only gives us access for the duration on a single request, whereas a session variable 'holds' its value for a much longer period of time.

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [Route("/Users/{userId}/Foos")]
    public IActionResult Index(int userId)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"] = userId; 
        //this.TempData["userId"] = userId;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Foos()
    {
        var userId = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"]; 
        //var userId = int.Parse(this.TempData["userId"].ToString());
        IEnumerable<Foo> foos = new Foo[0];
        //to keep this as small as possible for reproducing
        return this.Json(new { foos = foos });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/Foos/ToggleFlag")]
    public ActionResult ToggleFlag([FromBody] Foo foo)
    {
        //delegate updating to writer; omitted for reproducibility
        return this.Ok();
    }
}
```